# Is it possible to specify bandwidth consumption for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

Is it possible to specify to iOS what percentage of bandwidth the app should use when the app is uploading data to the server?

Or, is it possible in the code to use only said percentage of bandwidth available on the device while uploading data?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth is very variable, it is virtually impossible to know what bandwidth you have available at any given time on a wireless device. Is it on a cellular network or wifi network? Are you alone using those networks or are others using them too? There are many variables in this equation and the short answer is no, unless you have a very controlled environment.

You can of course tell your application programmatically to not use more than X KB/s and apply an algorithm to control that, but I feel that is not your question.